# Check url parameter in included php?

Tags: php

Do I understand correct that it is not possible to check an url parameter in an include php-file as below? Any work around?

main.php

```
<?php
include "included.php";
?>
```

included.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET["test"])){
    echo "ok";
}
?>
```

Comment: Can you change both files?  Why do you want to use `$_GET`?  Because included.php is used in other ways or what?

Comment: Correct included.php is a connection file for mysql used in other ways

Comment: if `test=something` is in the URL for main.php then the `$_GET` will be available in the included.php, if not and you want to specify it then just put `$_GET["test"] = 'something';` in main.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to check url parameters in your included.php file